# Cant access OpenStack instance from other devices

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, instance, openstack, ping

I have done a DevStack installation of OpenStack on a server.

I have added ICMP and SSH rules to the security group. And have made instances on it.

I can ssh and ping these instances from the host machine.

Now the problem is that I'm unable to ssh or even ping my instances from other machines on this network. And the fun part is that these instances can ssh/ping other machines and even ping my other server and ssh VM's on this server.

I hope I made sense but if you have more to ask, please let me know

Comment: Is the host a virtual or a physical server? Does it have a firewall? How is the Devstack cloud attached to that network? Can you share your `local.conf`? Do you get an error message when trying to access the instances? What is the "other server" that you talk about?

Comment: The host (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) is on a physical server. OpenStack is installed on it and I'm accessing it on my laptop using ssh and browser. Now from this laptop, I can ssh ubuntu and then also the instances on OpenStack. But I can't access the instance directly or ping it.

The other server is another test server with proxmox on it and it has VM's on it. The OpenStack instances can access these virtual machines.

Being an IT student I'm learning about these technologies.

Comment: When you try to ping the instances directly from your laptop, do you use floating IPs? What are the error symptoms? I forgot to ask if the instances are connected to the public network directly, or to a tenant network. I am also curious how the cloud is connected to the network (`local.conf` should contain that information).

Comment: Yes I'm using the floating IP's, and I'll share the local.conf here, please take alook at it

Comment: echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eno1/proxy_arp this worked out for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this worked out fine for me

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eno1/proxy_arp

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been trying thousands of things and nothing had worked for me, of everything I thought and tried if I imagined that it was something related to iptables or something similar where I needed to forward the communication but I had not been able to and this solution work at first.

Again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD=openstack
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
HOST_IP=192.168.4.72
enable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
enable_service h-eng h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw
enable_plugin heat git://git.openstack.org/openstack/heat
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.4.240/29
FLAT_INTERFACE=eno1
```